# Как создать новое поле с названием как у одного из полей родителя только с заменой и другим типом

Tags: kotlin

Код у родителя

```
var value: Byte = 0
```

Код у наследника

```
var value: Int = 0
```

И я хочу чтобы поле у наследника заменяло поле родителя. Теперь вопрос как это сделать? (на котлине)

Answer (score 0):

В наследнике

```
override var value: Int = 0
```

Но наверняка `Byte` родителя нельзя заменить на `Int` в наследнике, а наоборот, скорее всего, можно.

Comment: Не работает. Выдаёт ошибку, что надо либо присвоить тип как у родителя, либо поменять тип поля у самого родителя

Comment: Я предупреждал :)